# Why the variable is not visible?

Tags: php, xml

I have this kind of XML file with PHP processing instructions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?php
  $a = 8;
?>
<?php function add_some() { ?>
  <element attr="<?php echo $a ?>"/>
<?php } ?>

<elements>
  <?php
    add_some();
    add_some();
  ?>
</elements>
```

When I process it with `php test.xml`, I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<elements>
    <element attr="PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a in test.xml on line 5
"/>
  <element attr="PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a in test.xml on line 5
"/>
</elements>
```

Tell me how to fix it, please?

Comment: basic variable scope problem - `$a` is out of scope for the function: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working Because it's not defined in the function.

There are a few ways to go about this:

**1) Use global variable:**

```
 echo $a; // working
 function add_some() {
   global $a;
   echo $a; // working
```

**2) Pass it into the function if it's specific to that function:**

```
echo $a; // working
  function add_some($a) {
    echo $a; // working
```

Answer (score 1):

Please become familiar with PHP variable scope http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

In you case you should pass `$a` as parameter to `add_some()` or use `global $a;` in its body (but that is bad idea) otherwise it stays outside of visibility scope for `add_some()` function.

PS: discover any template engine (Smarty, Blaze) because spaghetti code is bad, bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

`$a` is outside of the function scope, you should define the variable inside the function or use it as an argument.

Read about the variable scopes:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?php function add_some($a) { ?>
<element attr="<?php echo $a ?>"/>
<?php } ?>

<elements>
    <?php
    add_some(8);
    add_some(8);
    ?>
</elements>
```

You should read the php manual for user-defined functions: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a global variable. Functions cannot read or write to global variables unless they are explicitly informed about them via the `global` keyword:

```
$foo = 'bar';
function some_func() {
    global $foo;
    echo $foo; //bar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?php
$a = 8;
function add_some() { ?>
<element attr="<?php global $a; echo $a; ?>"/>
<?php } ?>
<elements>
<?php
 add_some();
 add_some();
?>
</elements>
```